# Creating Loop and adding string

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to Create a loop and add the following below languages in the loop. Every time the loop runs, it should click on the language link and Verify the title exists.

```
 Deutsch =  Chemischer Stoff 

 Italiano =  Sostanza pura 

 Scots =   Frae Wikipedia 

 English =  Chemical substance
```

so far, this is the code i have

> string[] Languages = {"Deutsch", "Italiano", "Scots", "English" }; for
>   (int i = 0; i < Languages.Length; i++)

then what i want to see happen is that
Every time the loop runs, it should click on the language link and Verify the title exists.

Comment: That's a task. What is the question?

Comment: What have you tried so far? And where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Map<String, String> links = new HashedMap();
    links.put("Deutsch", "Chemischer Stoff");
    links.put("Italiano", "Sostanza pura");
    links.put("Scots", "Frae Wikipedia");
    links.put("English", "Chemical substance");

    for (String key : links.keySet()) {
        WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'" + key + "')]"));
        link.click();
        driver.getTitle().equals(links.get(key));
    }
```

NOTE:
Make sure you have the encoding set to **UTF-8** to support different characters other than english.